# How do you remove the "ffsearcher" trojan?

Tags: cleanup, malware

Does anyone have any experience in removing the ffsearcher trojan.

One of our systems is infected.  The virus scanner doesn't detect it, but our websense program is detecting all the internet activity from it.

I am trying to determine how to remove this.

Here is a great article on the virus, but no removal instructions.  Tells the files infected but not how to clean.

http://secureworks.com/research/threats/ffsearcher

Comment: Spelled 'trojan'.

Comment: What antivirus program are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the best way is to wipe the machine and restore from backup

Comment: You shouldn't trust a compromised machine. It might look like a "simple" compormise, but unless you have a mechanism to boot a trusted OS and insure that all binaries on the machine are original there may well be a "back door" lurking (rootkit, etc) even after you believe you've "cleaned" the machine. This is an old lesson in computer security that seems to be increasingly forgotten today.

Comment: That should be "trusted backup" - if you can't remember when you got the virus, then you can't trust the most recent backups. If there's no removal instructions, the best way to remove the infection is DBAN. Don't put yourself at risk for reinfection.

Answer (score 0):

Combofix can get rid of it, run MBAM after to finish up..